# Find the differences in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find the different for below arrays.

First array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 1
        [year] => 2014
        [Total_days] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 2
        [year] => 2014
        [Total_days] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 3
        [year] => 2014
        [Total_days] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 4
        [year] => 2014
        [Total_days] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 6
        [year] => 2014
        [Total_days] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 1
        [year] => 2015
        [Total_days] => 1
    ))
```

Second array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 1
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 2
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 3
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 4
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 6
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 5
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 6
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 7
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 2
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 8
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 1
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 9
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 1
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [MONTH] => 10
        [year] => 2014
        [total] => 2
    ))
```

Now how to find the total different between array2 to array1 for same year and same months?

For example In array2 has array [6] => Array
        (
            [MONTH] => 7
            [year] => 2014
            [total] => 2
        )

In array1 has the same year and month in the index array [4]. Here how to find the total difference as 2-1 = 1 ?

Comment: How do *you* think you'd find the difference? Start by iterating through the array using the key name to match both of the variables. Do *some* effort yourself. We're not your free labour.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `array_diff` method to find difference in `array`.

Answer (score 0):

First append the year,month and date....then find the difference using date_diff()